# Phabricator constraint always returns "Parameter \"constraints\" must be a map of constraints, got \"string\"."

Tags: phabricator, conduit

Am trying to populate google sheets using apps script by fetching from the API details of a specified ticket. However, the API always returns `Parameter \"constraints\" must be a map of constraints, got \"string\"."`

Tried it via curl and returns the same result.
`curl http://172.30.50.170/api/maniphest.search -d api.token="api-anefq57o5tw6cq23vuxcza6ubxui" -d constraints={"id":"14519"}`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`curl http://172.30.50.170/api/maniphest.search -d api.token="api-anefq57o5tw6cq23vuxcza6ubxui" -d constraints[ids][0]=14519`

Comment: It would be more helpful to explain why your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

with **conduit** you can access and try all API call, and there you can find the constraints structure for cURL.

1. Open /conduit
2. select any method, ex. maniphest-search
3. at the end of the page you will find a section called **Call Method**
4. After pressing **Call Method** then below it you can see example for cURL, ...

Cheers